# Determine set of items upto max n, which give the smallest total value and whose combined weights >= the capacity weight (knapsack problem variant)

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to run a variant of the knapsack problem whereby I need the item combo that gives the smallest total value but whose combined weight equals or surpasses the capacity weight.

```
maxn = 3
vm = [60, 100, 120, 50, 10, 10]  # Values
wt = [10, 20, 30, 20, 5, 5]  # Weights
W = 50  # Capacity weight
n = len(vm)
```

What I have, gives me the classic knapsack answer (the highest total value):

```
def knapsack(n, W, wt, vm):
    for i in range(n+1):
        for w in range(W+1):
            if i == 0 or w == 0: 
                K[i][w] = 0
            elif wt[i-1] <= w: 
                K[i][w] = max(vm[i-1]  
                    + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]],  K[i-1][w]) 
            else: 
                K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
    print(K[n][W])
    return K[n][W]

def items_in_optimal(n, W, wm):
    i = n
    j = W

    while (i > 0 and j > 0):
        if(K[i][j] != K[i-1][j]):
            print(i-1)
            j = j-wm[i-1]
            i = i-1
        else:
            i = i-1

K = [[0 for i in range(W + 1)] for j in range(n + 1)] 
knapsack(n, W, wt, vm)
items_in_optimal(n, W, wt)

Output: 
220
2
1
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
Output:
170
3
2
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Edited question to be clearer

Edit 2:
This is what I've come up with, but I'd be very interested if there's a faster method:

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

rlen = [2, maxn]
a = []
for r in rlen:
    best_value = sum(vm)
    for i in combinations(np.arange(0, len(vm)), r):
        if sum(np.array(wt)[list(i)]) >= W:
            if sum(np.array(vm)[list(i)]) < best_value:
                best_value = sum(np.array(vm)[list(i)])
                best_indices = list(i)
    a.append([r, best_value, best_indices])

split_inv = min(a, key=lambda t: t[1])[2]
print(split_inv)
```

Comment: Solve the classic variant and output items NOT included in the solution. Figure out what the capacity should be.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem mentioned that *smallest total value but whose combined weight equals or surpasses the capacity weight.* But the classic knapsack picks the weights whose sum never exceeds the capacity of the knapsack. So the classic one doesn't work unless some changes are done.

One way is to make the weights negative, then the list of weights will be :
`[-10, -20, -30, -20, -5, -5]`

Make the capacity also negative : `-50`

Then if you apply the classic algorithm on this modified list, i.e. pick weights whose total weight is less than or equal to the capacity and with minimum value, you would pick items `(3,4)` which has value of `170`.

Comment: It seems very logical, but unfortunately I wasn't able to get an answer other than 0 by turning the weights and capacity negative.

Comment: @at8865 It is a little tricky to implement but I think it should be doable.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 2D table where the rows represent weights from 0 to W, and the columns represent the number of items from 0 to N. Each entry should be a tuple: `(valid, value, indexList)`.

Initially, only `table[0][0]` is valid.

For each item, scan the table in reverse. In other words, the loops look like this:

```
items = zip(wt, vm)
for itemIndex, (itemWeight, itemValue) in enumerate(items):
    for w in range(W,-1,-1):
        for n in range(N-1,-1,-1):
```

Note that the `n` loop starts at `N-1`. An entry in column N of the table represents a list of N items, and therefore another item cannot be added to that entry.

When you find an entry `table[w][n]` that is valid, compute a new weight, value, and indexList by adding the current item to that entry. (If `w + itemWeight` is greater than W, then the new weight is W.) Then compare with the candidate entry `table[newWeight][n+1]`. If the candidate is not valid, or has a higher value, update the candidate. If the candidate is valid and has a lower value, don't change it.

Once all the items have been scanned, find the entry in the last row of the table that has the lowest value, and that's the answer.

For the given example, the final table is shown below. Only rows with valid entries are shown. The first column is the weight for that row.

```
 0 [(True , 0, []), (False,  0, []),  (False,  0, []),     (False,  0, [])]
 5 [(False, 0, []), (True,  10, [4]), (False,  0, []),     (False,  0, [])]
10 [(False, 0, []), (True,  60, [0]), (True,  20, [4, 5]), (False,  0, [])]
15 [(False, 0, []), (False,  0, []),  (True,  70, [0, 4]), (False,  0, [])]
20 [(False, 0, []), (True,  50, [3]), (False,  0, []),     (True,  80, [0, 4, 5])]
25 [(False, 0, []), (False,  0, []),  (True,  60, [3, 4]), (False,  0, [])]
30 [(False, 0, []), (True, 120, [2]), (True, 110, [0, 3]), (True,  70, [3, 4, 5])]
35 [(False, 0, []), (False,  0, []),  (True, 130, [2, 4]), (True, 120, [0, 3, 4])]
40 [(False, 0, []), (False,  0, []),  (True, 150, [1, 3]), (True, 140, [2, 4, 5])]
45 [(False, 0, []), (False,  0, []),  (False,  0, []),     (True, 160, [1, 3, 4])]
50 [(False, 0, []), (False,  0, []),  (True, 170, [2, 3]), (True, 180, [2, 3, 4])]
```

The last row shows that the lowest value for 2 items is 170, and the lowest value for 3 items is 180. So 170 is the lowest value overall.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you verify an entry's validity? The following ``` K = [[(False, 0, []) for i in range(N + 1)] for j in range(W + 1)]; K[0][0] = (True, 0, [])``` only gives me the first cell as valid, but I'm looping from the bottom up, so I'm confused

Comment: @at8865 Those two lines look correct. They should be followed by the four lines I put in the answer. Then the next two lines are `oldValid, oldValue, oldList = K[w][n]` and `if oldValid:`